# Derivative of function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following matlab code. 1st line after while gives error. i am trying to make Newtons method to find roots. for that i need derivative **f`(p0)**.
plz guide me what i am doing wrong and how can i get derivative of function **f**;

I also tried `D(f(p0))` but that didn't work, gives error: Undefined function or method 'D' for input arguments of type 'double'.

```
format long;
f=@(x) cos(x)-x;

p0 = 0.5;
TOLL = 1e-4;
N = 100;

i = 1;
while (i <= N)
    p = p0-f(p0)/diff(f(p0)); %Error, returns empty results this produced error

    if ( abs(p-p0) < TOLL)
        fprintf('Root of given equation is %f\n', p);
       return;
    end

    i=i+1;    
    p0 = p;
end

fprintf('Method failed after %d iteration\n', i);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because `p0` is a scalar, so `f(p0)` is a scalar. Then taking `diff(f(p0))` wont work.

To find the derivative at `p0`, you could use this definition of the derivative:

> `f'(p0)` = limit as `h->0` of `(f(x+h)-f(x))/h`.

Pick `h` as some small number (say `1e-3`), using `(f(p0+h)` and `f(p0))`, you should be able to get an approximation of the derivative of `f` at `p0`.

Comment: You can also use the two point derivate `(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/2h`, or `(-f(x+2*h)+8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/12/h` or ... There should be plenty of documentation on this. Anyway +1 of correct answer

Comment: Exactly what i needed. i just started matlab and didn't knew how to achive this. Your description helped. & @patrik ur idea is also valid & very useful information. thanks to both :)